# CSS selectors and combinations of tags

Tags: css, combinations, css-selectors

I have a sequences of

tags such like this

```
<div id="info">
    <h1>some title</h1>
    <p>some content</p>
    <h1>some title</h1>
    <p>some content</p>
    <h1>some title</h1>
    <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

I need an image separator after each

tag, but not after the last one

I have the following css styles defined:

```
#info {
    margin-left:245px;
    width: 545px;
}

#info h1{
    color:#000;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:100;
}

#info p{
    color:#6c6f70;
    font-size:22px;
}

#info p:last-child :after{
    content: "";
}

#info h1+p:after{
    content: " " url(../img/dotseparator.png);
    padding-top:25px;
    display:block;
    height:8px;
}
```

But I get the separator even after the last paragraph... Can you please help me with what is wrong in my styles?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 #info h1+p:not(last-of-type):after{
        content: " " url(../img/dotseparator.png);
        padding-top:25px;
        display:block;
        height:8px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

<-HR-> is simple for seperator [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vR2DU/9/)

```
<div id="info">
    <h1>some title</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>some content</p>
    <hr>
    <h1>some title</h1>
     <hr>
    <p>some content</p>
     <hr>
    <h1>some title</h1>
     <hr>
    <p>some content</p>
     <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted it to be "automatic" but I think I will use HR